# Capturing every group of word between '-'

Tags: regex, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I need to extract group of words out of a column in the database. Users saved terminus of bus line in a pretty nasty way, and I need to extract them.
For example :

```
'Bétheny La Couturelle - Croix Cordier - Tinqueux Champ Paveau'  
- {Bétheny La Couturelle}  
- {Croix Cordier}    
- {Tinqueux Champ Paveau}
```

I've tried this pattern:

```
,'([a-zA-Zéèàîùê]+(\s|\-)?)+', 'g');
```

ex :

`````
select regexp_matches('Bétheny La Couturelle - Croix Cordier - Tinqueux Champ Paveau','([a-zA-Zéèàîùê]+(\s|\-)?)+','g')````
`````

The 'g' flag for capturing every matches.
But it doesn't work.
All I obtain was :

```
- {e , }  
- {r , }  
- {u,NULL}
```

How may I succeed ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is because of capturing groups. You should use non-capturing ones. However, you should never use `(a+b?)+` or ``(?:a+b?)+`` patterns as they tend to lead to catastrophic backtracking. Always make sure (if possible) that patterns matching at the same locations are not following one another in immediate succession.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
SELECT regexp_matches('Bétheny La Couturelle - Croix Cordier - Tinqueux Champ Paveau','[a-zA-Zéèàîùê]+(?:[\s-][a-zA-Zéèàîùê]+)*','g')
```

See the [online demo](https://rextester.com/WYBSRQ18750).

Or, if the delimiter is always `<spaces><-><spaces>` you may use a splitting approach:

```
SELECT regexp_split_to_table('Bétheny La Couturelle - Croix Cordier - Tinqueux Champ Paveau', '\s+-\s+')
```

See [another demo](https://rextester.com/YNAA10083).

**Pattern details**

- `[a-zA-Zéèàîùê]+` - 1 or more letters in the character class
- `(?:[\s-][a-zA-Zéèàîùê]+)*` - 0 or more sequences of

  - `[\s-]` - a whitespace or `-` (note it is equivalent to `[[:space:]-]`)
  - `[a-zA-Zéèàîùê]+` - 1 or more letters in the character class.

In the splitting code, `\s+-\s+` matches 1+ whitespaces, `-` and again 1+ whitespaces.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It works. Problem solved I think.
Just to clarify : 
    '?:' says that I don't want to catch space or '-'. Is that it ? 
But in the case of 'Trois-Puits - Trépail' I catch 'Trois-Puits' and 'Trépail' (and this is what I intend to). 
I'm a bit confused.
PS. Thanks for the link to the demo I desperatly tried to find an online demo for postgresql and not java or php.

Comment: @Brindavoine `(?:...)` is a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions). As per PostgreSQL docs, `regexp_matches` *returns a text array whose n'th element is the substring matching the n'th parenthesized subexpression of the pattern (not counting "non-capturing" parentheses)* if the pattern contains parenthesized subexpressions,

Comment: @Brindavoine `[a-zA-Zéèàîùê]+` is a bracket expression that matches 1 or more occurrences of ASCII letters (`a-zA-Z` part does that) or some extended letters (from the `éèàîùê` set). The fact that `[\s-]` only matches 1 whitespace/hyphen and `[a-zA-Zéèàîùê]+` matches 1 or more letters makes it possible to avoid matching `space`-`hyphen`-`space` strings.

Comment: Just seen two functions in PostgreSQL for splitting. Would it be an option here?

Comment: If it is always `<space><-><space>`, `try regexp_split_to_table` with `'\s+-\s+'`